# TypeScript imports causing all other code to disappear

Tags: typescript, jasmine

So I have a bunch of classes in `root/app/providers/engine/engine.ts`. In my test spec file `spec/engine/engine-spec.ts` (the `spec/` folder is also where the jasmine `support/` is) I have a basic test:

```
///<reference path="../../typings/globals/jasmine/index.d.ts"/>
// By the way this typings reference does exist

import {ClassA, ClassB, ClassC, ClassD, ClassE, EnumThing} from '../../app/providers/engine/engine';

describe('In the classes,', () => {
    describe('ClassA', () => {
        it('exists', () => {
            expect(new ClassA()).toBeDefined();
        });
    });
});
```

In my `gulpfile` I've set up the `test` task to run this thing through `tsc` and then call `jasmine`. However, with the example shown above Jasmine finds no specs and just exits. The output file that `tsc` generates is this:

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
};
///<reference path="../../../typings/globals/lodash/index.d.ts"/>
///<reference path="../../../typings/globals/chance/index.d.ts"/>
// }}}
///<reference path="../../typings/globals/jasmine/index.d.ts"/>
```

As you can see, this is just TypeScript's implementation of class `extends`, and all the specs have poofed!

If I comment out the import and just run a basic `expect(true).toBe(true)` test, then it works fine - Jasmine finds one spec and it succeeds. The `output.spec.js` also looks expected:

```
///<reference path="../../typings/globals/jasmine/index.d.ts"/>
describe('In the classes,', function () {
    describe('ClassA', function () {
        it('exists', function () {
            expect(true).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```

Despite this being the case, I'll just put the `gulp test` task here if it is the problem:

```
// At the top
var gulp = require('gulp');
var tsc = require('gulp-typescript');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawnSync;

// Few unrelated tasks later ...

gulp.task('test', function(done) {
    var stream = gulp.src('spec/**/*.spec.ts')
        .pipe(tsc({
            out: 'output.spec.js',
            target: 'es5'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('spec/'));

    stream.on('end', function() {
        spawn('jasmine', ['--color', 'spec/output.spec.js'], {
            stdio: 'inherit'
        })
        done();
    });
});
```

The issue seems to be with `tsc` itself, but I don't know how to figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that in this situation, imports don't work. Instead, adding a `///<reference path="..."/>` comment (with the `...` replaced by the path) works.

This is very strange behaviour. Though I found the answer that works, I would still very much like if someone edited this answer or added a comment to explain why this is the case.

Thanks!